# I'm unable to pass empty value to html attributes if no key in object. Please suggest this, how can i do this in betterway

Tags: javascript, jquery, underscore.js

After the form submission, I'm passing form errors (response.data object values) using underscore js function _.mapObject to HTML elements using .error-key class, but after the next form submission, I'm unable to clear the previous form errors.

AXIOS Request:

```
.then(function (response) {
    _.mapObject(response.data, function(error_value, error_key){
        if(error_key)
        {
            $('.error-'+error_key).html(error_value);    
        }
        else
        {
            $('.error-'+error_key).html('');    
        }
    });
})
```

HTML error display element under each form element:

```
<p class="font-small text-danger error-name"></p>
```

I tried this one -> After the form submission, I updated the element error statements with blank as $('.text-danger').html(' ');. It worked but clearing all values and updating these is not an effective solution I believe.

I am trying to just clear the old error statements if the object doesn't have a key. Can anyone suggest how to remove the error statements if the response.data object doesn't have key for each request?

Comment: You write `if(key)`, do you mean to write `if(error_key)`? And you're not `return`ing anything in the `mapObject` callback. Does underscore have a `eachObject` or something you can use instead?

Comment: Yeah, sorry. It's error_key. I will edit this.

Comment: I kind of doubt that error_key is ever null or falsey, so that means your else probably never runs.  And if it did it would try to set the html of `$('.error-')`

Comment: There is _.each() function like foreach in JS. It gives the same result to me but after the collection of keys and values, I'm unable to remove the error statements which i have passed. Searching for a function logic like "hasnot keys in Object then no errors else erros" for each request.

Comment: You should write a function that clears *all* form errors, and call that before you validate again.